# Flutter : set default image in Image.file

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm currently creating **Updating Image** process in Flutter app.

I already succeed getting image that pass from some widget defined in **View.dart** to UpdateScreen widget defined in **Update_screen.dart** by using `Network Image`.

```dart
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 100,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    '${Urls.BASE_API_IMAGE}/${widget.imageUpdate}'),
              ),
```

My question is, how to set default image using `Image.file()` ? , because I must use `Image.file()` for updating data.

**Thank's**

#### My full source code :

[My Full Source Code Here](https://pastebin.com/vuSYWing)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) as it makes it simple to set a default image.

Example

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "your url",
        placeholder: (context, url) =>Your default Image Widget(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```